# iPhone app Testflight build crashes on iPad only since Xcode 7

Tags: xcode7, testflight

I do have an iPhone only app which I built via Xcode 7.2.1 and submitted it to Apple.

The app got rejected because it crashes on iPad during startup - I can reproduce this behavior with when doing a Testflight build and install it on my iPad, it runs without any problems on iPhone or with debug builds on simulator/iPad.

How can I track this down? Once I got a Crashlytics report like

```
application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

but my window is created

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

and used the `rootViewController` property is set on the window.